# Linux (uclinux 2.4.x)

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel, kernel, uclinux

I have one doubt.
Using uclinux 2.4.x. In this linux I have my own adapter code for reading the frames from ingress port.
Have added a debug log at exact place from where reading frames word by word and it is sure that I received all number of frames transmitted by peer.
( at Layer2 I am receiving all frames).

From here onward now invoking "netif_rx" to send all received framer to upper layer (i.e Network layer and Transport Layer).

Doubt : I observe that there are some drop of packets at (Transport Layer)UDP protocol.
How did I confirm: Added a count check at Layer 1 and Layer3(UDP Layer) and both counts are not equal.

that means even if we receiving all framer from layer 1 but when it reaching to UDP in between somewhere drop is happening.

So, Could any one suggest that where exactly the problem could be, How to check if memory is full or skb_alloc is not happening for more packets at UDP layer.

Kindly suggest your opinion, It will be of great help and support.

Please let me know if you need more information.

BR
Karn

Comment: take a look at [dropwatch](https://fedorahosted.org/dropwatch/)

Comment: Hi Every one, increased the rmem_default and rmem_max size in /proc/sys/net/core to 64 MB from 128 KB and observed that able to read more number of UDP packets,is any one have a good idea that how do we calculate the rmem_max and rmem_default size in kernel? is it based on Physical Memory or Not? If yes please let me know the calculation.  Kindly reply . Your suggestion is important.